# Switch case error on libs

Tags: java, android

I have an error on implementing a library module to my Android apps. 
it says:

```
Constant expression required Resource IDs cannot be used in a switch statement in Android library modules less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Validates using resource IDs in a switch statement in Android library module. Resource IDs are non final in the library projects since SDK tools r14, means that the library code cannot treat these IDs as constants.
```

and here is my code:

```
private void changeWeekStart(@IdRes int selection) {
        switch (selection) {
            case R.id.action_week_start_saturday:
                CalendarUtils.sWeekStart = Calendar.SATURDAY;
                break;
            case R.id.action_week_start_sunday:
                CalendarUtils.sWeekStart = Calendar.SUNDAY;
                break;
            case R.id.action_week_start_monday:
                CalendarUtils.sWeekStart = Calendar.MONDAY;
                break;
        }
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .edit()
                .putInt(CalendarUtils.PREF_WEEK_START, CalendarUtils.sWeekStart)
                .apply();
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        mCoordinator.reset();
    }
```

Please help me to change from `switch-case` to `if-else` code.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everywhere you have a `case`, that will become the condition of an `if` statement; a `break` statement will correspond with a closing `}` on an `if` statement.

```
if (selection == R.id.action_week_start_saturday) {
    CalendarUtils.sWeekStart = Calendar.SATURDAY;
} else if (selection == R.id.action_week_start_sunday) {
    CalendarUtils.sWeekStart = Calendar.SUNDAY;
} else if (selection == R.id.action_week_start_monday) {
    CalendarUtils.sWeekStart = Calendar.MONDAY;
}
```

Note that you do not supply a default case in your switch-case block so it is possible that `CalendarUtils.sWeekStart` is not modified if the `selection` parameter has a value different from the ones you've considered.